# Fancybox 1.2.5 callbackOnShow - I have some syntax errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I am trying to run a function when the box loads, for v1.2.5 it seems it should be the callbackOnShow attribute. Here is my code, I have a syntax error but as I am a noob, I am having trouble figuring it out.

```
$("a#inline").fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'autoDimensions': false,
            'frameWidth': 932,
            'frameHeight': 496,
            'padding': '0',
            'overlayOpacity': '0.7',
            'callbackOnShow': $(function () {
$('#palette').on('mouseover', 'a', function (event) {
    $('#PaletteColorName').text("Color: " + event.target.title);
});
$('#palette').on('mouseleave', 'a', function () {
    $('#PaletteColorName').text("Color: ");
});
});
```

Possible alternatives are welcome to. Here is a fiddle version of what I am trying to get functioning inside the fancybox.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheEks/TFGxJ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things there. You shouldn't enclose the options in quotes.

```
$("a#inline").fancybox({
   hideOnContentClick: false,
   autoDimensions: false
   //etc...
});
```

Next, you're not specifying your callback functions quite right. By writing a function like this: `callBack: $(function() { ... });` That function will actually be executed. You don't want that... you want the function to run on a certain event. So what you should do is this:

```
$('a#inline').fancybox({
    callbackOnShow: function() {
        $('#palette').on('mouseover', 'a', function(event) {
            //...
        });
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if it's that way in the text editor you're using, or the formatting just got messed up when you pasted the code here, but while not strictly necessary, it's a *very* good idea to use proper indenting. It makes it a lot easier to spot syntax errors.

Finally, you should consider installing [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox, if you don't have it already. It will help you out with figuring out where you have a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I was able to get Fancybox to start functioning again with that callback defined, however, the script still isn't working in there.
And yes, the spacing was just copying it over here, it's indented correctly in my code(I'm not an amimal!)

Comment: @TheEks : you can enclose the options in quotes, there is not any issue with that, however Boolean and integer values definitively shouldn't be enclosed in quotes. This, for instance `'overlayOpacity': '0.7'`  should rather be `'overlayOpacity': 0.7` ...notice the option remains enclosed in quotes but not the integer value,  otherwise it will trigger a js error.

Comment: @JFK Thanks for the explanation! I'll keep that in mind as I go on.